# Writing to a comma delimited text file

Tags: c#

I am having a difficult time with finding how to write to a comma delimited text file. I am creating a very basic address form for myself. I would like when I click button1 that it creates a text file then writes the data from textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, and maskedtextbox1 to that file seperated by commas.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: There is no question here.  What is your question?

Comment: the question is at the top. I would like to know how to write the information that was entered to a text file.

Comment: Questions end with a question mark (?).   Other than wanting-something-you-don't-have, what are you having difficulty with? What have you tried? and what don't you understand?

Answer (score 6):

Creating csv files is very easy.  Try the following:

```
string s1 = TextBox1.Text;
string s2 = TextBox2.Text;
string s3 = TextBox3.Text;
string s4 = maskedtextbox1.Text;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\text.txt", true))  // True to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file
{
    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("[0],[1],[2],[3]", new object[] { s1, s2, s3, s4 }));
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't like the string.Format method, you could do the following:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\text.txt", true))
{
    sw.WriteLine(s1 + "," + s2 + "," + s3 + "," + s4}));
}
```

Comment: Or: `sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new object[] { s1, s2, s3, s4 }));`

Comment: Your comment in the code is incorrect. The second parameter to StreamWriter is true to append, false to overwrite.

Comment: @JBrooks - thanks for the comment.  Someone finally caught that after 2.5 years :)

Comment: Or `File.CreateText` rather than `new StreamWriter(...)` Or `File.AppendText` if you want to append.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use two classes: FileStream and StreamWriter.  And maybe [this documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).  But as I suspect that this is a homework assignment, I'm leery to provide any more assistance.  You should be able to figure it out easily enough.